# Which measure indicates a smooth variation of data?

Tags: math, image-processing, opencv, statistics

I am trying to compare text and non-text regions based on the thickness of lines/strokes. Using the distance transform and some fiddling thereafter, managed to obtain the thickness (actually half the thickness) of each stroke comprising the features in a picture.

Here's a typical result of a program run:

1.Text region

> 34444433343554335533553555545544455445533444444344455435553335545556665444445654444444444444444444444444455434554554455444456544444445555445555543355556665544665444535444553354434553444444444444455444445544444454444444444444444444444444455442444444554444444544444444444444554444456444554414454444444444444444444554444445543454445443444544434443344443334442133223332221

1. Non-text

> 1111112222212222222213333232111112234444411415445125544126143211123445716422457887433442222991443110103332222113111163124134444312122222222224551313122222222222243455553141432222222232111422222351515513211134161412234411743111111454181813111434555191113145520111322223334554452121204233145433467891011121311732525252524202022213137326252419192112222222335831818204233332222344315625171714334444451111788992225161619334538215151811341234258811414113111223144488242413131711332543444872416135247724113223544356152554433333332666652323151444444336675523151344443335566523881333444552222113344445514141433345555202120141114444444345201433355644454191313322333474351818134322266657342171266672415161131145657419111421316665581447891113151513135555555586745556555588551214145145335557888755141314774333455886555141011111211981417776348524111099814144444556414341181114135447434567845534444334881088891011111213141113477734444379888881414144477437254448998834733764226777753781313577776677654466665753466712124666645444551124476735456655444432446663254664411476757773464147322222777455332224237738833223378121242311333378583438869913135923222344338101013139943333115533910111111884112155339910101011111111101111111097777778855544553991010111111111111111110999999101111111110777764111113561091097543434552999989998666544436554888778755554455541444465554317777774555555544455556665555564424443356433222345222124422341111312111214411322222223222231221143334424322342222123536411441664431775446548856766655885555664444644665449876444477544227887772

So is there any statistical measure more sophisticated than standard deviation that will indicate the difference in the two datasets: one varies gradually while the second one has drastic variations?
(included the scary numbers to illustrate what I'm attempting to quantize!)

Also please note that the number of data points will not be same, as i'll be comparing different regions with some experimentally determined threshold of SD (or some other measure), not regions among themselves.

Comment: Are your regions separated, with either text or non-text contents, or do you have a single list of thicknesses from which you want to extract text and non-text regions?

Comment: separate regions found by connected-component analysis, with the classification as text/non-text based on the result of the statistical measure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thought that comes to my mind is that you could do a wavelet transform on a chunk then look at the average energy associated with high frequency wavelets.

If you're not familiar with wavelets, the simplest to describe is the [Haar wavelet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haar_wavelet).  Assuming that the number of points you have sampled is 2<sup>n</sup>, you can calculate that as follows:

1. Divide your data into pairs of points.
2. Take 1/2 of the difference.  That is the coefficient of the detail wavelet.
3. Take the average of each pair.  This gives you 2<sup>n-1</sup> points.  Recursively do a wavelet transform on those.

For each level of the Haar wavelet, take the average of the square of the coefficient.  If your data really looks like what you've described, this statistic for the first few levels will be very different.  Experiment, decide where your threshold is, and you'll probably have a pretty reliable test.  (I would recommend having 3 possible answers from your test, "Text", "Not text", "unclear".  Look at the "unclear" examples and then improve your test.)

Comment: I'm reading up on Haar wavelets. Will try this method along with others suggested and see which gives most suitable results.

Comment: could you please explain what is meant by the "level" of Haar wavelet. Is it the values i get after step 3. before the next recursive run on the points? Also most resources on the web divide the data points by sqrt(2) rather than 2 - will that be any different in this implementation?

Comment: @AruniRC: Considering that I'm going off of memories of something I last saw in the mid 90s, feel free to go with "most resources on the web".  Though it will be useful for you either way.  As for level, the results of your first pass through 2**n points is the first detail level.  The results of the second pass through the 2**(n-1) averaged points is the second detail level.  And so on.

Answer (score 3):

If you are interested in measuring the smoothness, the standard deviation of the *differences* between adjacent thicknesses should be much smaller for text than non-text.

You can thus simply convert

> 34444433343554335533553555545544455445533444444344455435553335545556665444445654444444444444444444444444455434554554455444456544444445555445555543355556665544665444535444553354434553444444444444455444445544444454444444444444444444444444455442444444554444444544444444444444554444456444554414454444444444444444444554444445543454445443444544434443344443334442133223332221

into

> 1000(-1)000…

(1 = 4-3, 0 = 4-4, etc.).  The standard deviation of this list of differences is small, for text regions (in your example, this list contains many zeros).

If you need to keep using numbers between 0 and 9 for the thickness difference between thickness `t1` and thickness `t2`, you can perform a rescaling: `round((t2-t1+9)/2)`.

Comment: thanks a lot. will try all suggestions and then decide which one works best, though this looks way simpler.